# Keyboard does not open when display alertview with Textfield in ios 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I have created AlertView with TextField using this code:

```
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"The person you selected does not have an email address on file. Please enter their email address below." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",@"Submit",nil];
alert.tag = 1;
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
alertTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Email address";
[alert show];
```

It display fine and open keyboard in ios 6 or latter but not in ios 5.

Here is my device screenshot which run on ios 5.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code and its does not show keyboard in iOS 5 as you said but i have just added `resignFirstResponder` in your textField after alert show and its worked. Here is the code,

```
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"The person you selected does not have an email address on file. Please enter their email address below." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",@"Submit",nil];
alert.tag = 1;
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
// assert(alertTextField);
alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
alertTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Email address";
[alert show];
[alertTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

And if you don't want to `resignFirstResponder` in iOS 6 and later than put this code at the end of your code instead of `resignFirstResponder` code than textField only `resignFirstResponder` for iOS version less than 6.0

```
float currentVersion = 6.0;     
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < currentVersion)
  {
     [alertTextField resignFirstResponder];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with

```
    UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
```

you also write

```
alertTextField.delegate = self;
```

And in your header file (i.e. .h), pass textfield delegate like <`UITextFieldDelegate`>

Comment: can you give me the log for alertTextField?

Comment: You got your answer.So no need for any log now

Answer (score 0):

try with different keyboardTypes like `UIKeyboardTypeDefault`, `UIKeyboardTypePhonePad`, etc.

Also try `[alertTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`

`alertTextField.delegate = self;`

then in the delegate method,

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {     
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing method was called");
    if (!self.window.isKeyWindow) {
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}
```

not pretty sure, but hope this works for you..

Answer (score 0):

try this it is run on ios 5

```
CGRect textFieldFrame = CGRectMake(15.0f, 105.0f, 255.0f, 31.0f);

UITextField *txtYourTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldFrame];

txtYourTextField.placeholder = @"Your String";
txtYourTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
txtYourTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
txtYourTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
txtYourTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txtYourTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
txtYourTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
txtYourTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
txtYourTextField.delegate=self;

txtYourTextField.contentVerticalAlignment =    UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
txtYourTextField.tag = 1;
txtYourTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"The person you selected does not have an email address on file. Please enter their email address below.\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Send",nil];
alert.tag=1;

[alert addSubview:txtYourTextField];
[alert show];
```

Hope this helps you!!!